# AngularJS - e2e testing - Why does this by.css selector work?

Tags: angularjs, css-selectors, protractor

So I'm starting to break into AngularJS from a JavaScript (& jQuery) background. I've been wading through the tutorial, and an loving the way it's set up. Currently I'm looking at [lesson 10](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_10) and I can't figure out why a piece of the code works. I have tried googling and poking through the documentation...the protractor docs don't even seem to have anything for by.css and I couldn't figure out how to search for this very concisely :/ ... Apologies if I'm just missing something seriously obvious.

In the e2e test scenario there is this code:

```
it('should swap main image if a thumbnail image is clicked on', function() {
  element(by.css('.phone-thumbs li:nth-child(3) img')).click();
  expect(element(by.css('img.phone')).getAttribute('src')).toMatch(/img\/phones\/nexus-s.2.jpg/);

  element(by.css('.phone-thumbs li:nth-child(1) img')).click();
  expect(element(by.css('img.phone')).getAttribute('src')).toMatch(/img\/phones\/nexus-s.0.jpg/);
});
```

which acts on this page-html:

```
<ul class="phone-thumbs ng-scope">
  <li ng-repeat="img in phone.images" class="ng-scope">
    <img ng-src="img/phones/nexus-s.0.jpg" ng-click="setImage(img)" src="img/phones/nexus-s.0.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>
```

produced by this ng-markup:

```
<ul class="phone-thumbs">
  <li ng-repeat="img in phone.images">
    <img ng-src="{{img}}" ng-click="setImage(img)">
  </li>
</ul>
```

I can't figure out why the element(by.css('img.phone'))... is functional. Based on the selector (and coming from jQuery) I would expect to see a 'phone' class on the images...but it's not there. Does the '.phone' reference something else?

I can see that removing the '.phone' portion gives '.....warning: more than one element found for locator By.cssSelector("img") - you may need to be more specific', so how is '.phone' providing that specificity?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just looking in the wrong place:

It is checking if clicking on a thumbnail

```
//app/partials/phone-detail.html (line 9):
<img ng-src="{{img}}" ng-click="setImage(img)">
```

makes THIS image:

```
//app/partials/phone-detail.html (line 1):
<img ng-src="{{mainImageUrl}}" class="phone">
```

change it's source.  `img.phone` is exactly what you would expect.

The docs for `by.css` are here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md

Comment: Perfect, thanks...too much code waded through today, appreciate the help and the docs link!